# Wamp server is not accessilbe form other computer even settings are changed

Tags: php, wamp

Wamp server 3.0.4 httpd.conf contains

```
   <Directory "c:/wamp64/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        #Require all granted
    Allow from all

    </Directory>
```

And website is on **put Online** but still it is not accessible and shwong:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19 Server at 192.9.210.161 Port 80
```

Comment: you sure that c:/wamp64/cgi-bi  is fine ?

Comment: checked AllowOverride All  ?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman problem still persist

Comment: @MichałG what is this

Comment: @MichałG cgi-bin folder is empty

Comment: is c:/wamp64/cgi-bi  is a place wheris  your website  ?

Comment: nope my website is in www

Comment: @MichałG i copied my web in cgi-bi but problem still persist

Comment: By default the `httpd.conf` file does not contain the section that you show `<Directory "c:/wamp64/cgi-bin">` So you have messed up your `httpd.conf` file

Comment: You had better show all your `httpd.conf` file So we can unpick the mistakes